# Using openpyxl: KeyError: '.mpo' while saving Excel workbook

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I wrote a basic script to open an existing .xlsx workbook and add pictures to certain cells from my local drive. It works fine for most pictures. However, for one picture i get:

```
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site
    packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 345, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
    File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266, in save_workbook
    writer.save(filename)
    File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 248, in save
    self.write_data()
    File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 98, in write_data
    self.manifest._write(archive, self.workbook)
    File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\openpyxl\packaging\manifest.py", line 171, in _write
    self._register_mimetypes(filenames=archive.namelist())
    File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
    packages\openpyxl\packaging\manifest.py", line 183, in 
    _register_mimetypes
    mime = mimetypes.types_map[ext]
    KeyError: '.mpo'
```

Can anyone help me understand what this error means? Thanks

Comment: extension is `.mpo`

Comment: @codekaizer The image file is  `R_2fe1tQeZCtmTzdd~DJI_0004.JPG` . How would I see that it is actually .mpo?

Comment: check image mime type if it is `image/mpo`. if not, file an issue in openpyxl group.

Comment: Figured it out using this solution.  https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1138

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me.

from PIL import JpegImagePlugin
JpegImagePlugin._getmp = lambda: None